# Angular observable caching data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an angular project which is built on Angular 6, and my API is **.net core 
2.1.**

I have implemented pagination.
Calling my pagination method in my **.net core** API using postman works perfectly well. 
From the angular end, I use an observable. On the `ngOnInit` event, I call the `fetchRecords()` function and the first 10 records are displayed. when I click next, I call the `fetchRecords()` method again passing in the correct pagination parameters, but the page still maintains the first 10 records, I also noticed in the console.log() the records coming from the API are still the same first 10 records. I have a refresh button which calls the `fetchRecords()` method again, when i click on the refresh button immediately, nothing changes. But if i wait for about 7+ seconds, the next 10 records are displayed.
Is there some sort of caching done in my observable that keeps hold of request response for some seconds? If so, how do i rectify this?

```
/* My Fetch Requests method in my component.ts */

fetchRecords(){

let requestData:any = {
   skip: (this.page * this.rowsPerPage) - this.rowsPerPage,
   take: this.rowsPerPage
}


this.api.post('apiUrl/fetchRecords', requestData).subscribe(res=>{ // this is where i subscribe
 console.log('results', res); // Does not change unless delayed for 10 seconds
}
error=>{

})

}



goToNextPage(){
  this.page = this.page + 1;
    this.fetchRecords(); 
}

goToPreviousPage(){
  this.page = this.page - 1;
    this.fetchRecords();
}



/* Post Method */

post(url, obj) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/${url}`, obj, this.options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to tell more details about `this.api.post('apiUrl/fetchRecords', requestData).`

Comment: You're probably getting a race condition somewhere in your angular. Trying to use the new value before it is completly loaded

Comment: @ABOS Ok I have updated the question.

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer But when i call the .net core api from postman the results are okay

Comment: why you can still use response.json?

Comment: if you put `console.log`before `return response.json();`, does it also take 7+ seconds to print response?

Comment: What do you see in a network tab development tools?

Comment: @AbEbube Postman doen't care when the response comes. Javascript does.

Comment: how do you store the information from the observable ? the part where right now the console.log is

Comment: when i put console.log before return response.json it happens immediately.

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer i assign it to an array variable. which i bind to a table.

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer and from the log, i can see the repeated values.

Comment: do you log the value you get or the variable you're assigning it to

Comment: yes i log both and its the incorrect repeated values im seeing.

Comment: Try to use another child component in your component.ts and assign the this.api.post to an observable variable and send it to child component with async pipe. and also remove the map operator and return response.json();. if still your response not in json, in your child component do it. if you need more code, please let me know to write it as an answer

Comment: hmm from my observation so far, i placed a breakpoint in my api (visual studio) and the first call hits it correctly, but the preceeding ones with repeating values never hit the api untill 7+ seconds later

Comment: you do not have any ngIf in your HTML or something else? because without actual code I cannot do much more help. the another explanation might be the subscription (which I suggest to avoid subscription as much as possible ) . in your ngOnInit you already subscribe to api, and by calling fetch method, you are subscribing again. This was the reason that I suggest to use async pipe and push your to a child component and in your child component add changeDetection onPush.

Comment: what is the initial value for `this.page` ?

Comment: move also all the page DATA dependencies to child component and try!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
Apparently I'm just realising angular caches responses from http requests. I tried adding no-cache Cache Control headers and all that but it didnt work. What eventually worked was appending a unique date string to my post url as a parameter (Successfully making each request url unique) and my requests have been loading fine now even in quick succession. Heres a snippet of the code

```
post(url, obj) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/${url}`+ "?"+new Date().toString(), obj, this.options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your contributions.